# jqGrid - Is it possible to capture focusOut event

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

We are using jqGrid to render table data. Grid allows user to edit multiple row in one go from header.
[image]

I need to put some validation in case one or more rows are updated and user move out from jqGrid. Is there any focus out event?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Its huge java script file. finding it difficult to share code